# return first element not empty element of array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that can have words and spaces.
I want to return the first word inside the string.

My method was:

- apply `.split(' ')` to it to remove the white spaces.
- do `.filter(function(el){ return (el != '') }`
- get the first element by using `[0]`

**Is there a more optimized way to this? Maybe regex?**

My code:

```
var string = "  foo  bar ";
function getFirst(str) {
    var separatedString = str.split(' ');
    separatedString = separatedString.filter(function (el) {
        return (el != '')
    })
    return separatedString[0];
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uWr2K/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably closest equivalent of your code will be this line:

```
var word1 = s.replace(/\s*(\S+).*/, '$1');
```

Since you're splitting by space so this code will just grab the very first non-space substring from given input.

Comment: +1 for new alternative. [Compared](http://jsperf.com/get-first-class) and will go for dystroy's alternative, but apreciate the new idea (to me) of using replace. Thank you!

Comment: Your solution accepts `foo-bar` and in that case it is [the fastest](http://jsperf.com/get-first-class/3)... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
var firstWord = string.match(/\S+/)[0];
```

Comment: +1 for faaast answer. This is a filter for CSS classes. So by "word" I mean a word that is a valid CSS class name. I want to filter away empty spaces and just use the first class in case there are many.

Comment: @Rikard So I guess this will do ( `"  foo3_  bar ".match(/\w+/)[0];` => `"foo3_"` )

Comment: If it's used to filter css-classes, this would not be sufficient: `' foo-bar foo bar '.match(/\w+/)[0]` returns `'foo'`

Comment: Kooilnc, good point! Dystroy, any ideas? Apparently a class with `-` would be left out...

Comment: @Rikard For that case, use string.match(/\S+/)[0];

Answer (score 1):

You could <strike>use `trim` and</strike>   split on multiple spaces and use `string.length` in your filter:

```
function getFirst(str) {
    var separatedString = str.split(/\s+/).filter( function (el) {
           return el.length;
        });
    return separatedString[0];
}
getFirst(' foo-bar foo bar bar@foo  '); //=> 'foo-bar'
```